# Generator of a solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

In $\mathbb{F}_3$, consider:

$a+b+2c+d=0$

$2a+c+d=0$

$2a+b+c=0$

I got $a=0$, $c=-d$ and $b=d$, so we have $\mathbb{L}=\left \{ t \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\-1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} : t \in \mathbb{F}_3 
  \right \}$. Does this mean that $(0,1,-1,1)^T$ is the generator of the solution space?

Comment: The solution is wrong since the first equation isn't satisfied when $\;t=1\pmod 3\;$ ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help - how can I go about this problem?

Comment: Read down my answer

Comment: Many thanks! :)

Comment: Any time.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And easy way: form and then bring to echelon form the coefficients' matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
2&0&1&1\\
1&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}\implies\begin{cases}d=0=b\\{}\\a=-c=2c\end{cases}$$

so the general solution is

$$\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}2c\\0\\c\\0\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}=t\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\,,\,\,t\in\Bbb F_3=\text{Span}_{\Bbb F_3}\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;\right\}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, the first equation actually is $a+b+2c+d=0$. Do you get the same as I did in the question now?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Yes, I do ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$